# Reason to upgrade ubuntu server 14.04 to 16.04 on low end vps?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, upgrade

Having looked over a bunch of the docs, I have yet to find any compelling reason to upgrade Ubuntu server 14.04 on a low end (512MB digital ocean) droplet. I don't need ZFS, and am not sure why I would want systemd -- and these seem to be the only server focused changes of any import.

More importantly though, I was wondering if the memory usage/footprint and/or performance would be any different/better/worse on the same machine. I can't find any links that discuss this aspect.

Can anyone explain to me why I would want to upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

In general:

You should always apply security updates and relevant bug fixes and keep your servers current.
(Which some people also call upgrading but with regards to enterprise distributions that is not quite the same.)

You upgrade to a new major release:

- When (or rather a bit before) you current (major) OS release is no longer supported. For Ubuntu [LTS Server](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) that's 5 years after the [release date](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).  (On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS you're good till 2019.)
- If you need features only present in the new major release.
- If the applications that you run need upgrading and require newer versions of libraries and other dependancies only found in a new release.
- When your life cycle management policy demands it.
- When it is opportune (i.e. if you need to replace your server hardware the timing is logical for OS upgrade as well)

> I was wondering if the memory usage/footprint and/or performance would be any different/better/worse on the same machine.

Do you have actually have any performance problems that you think might benefit from upgrading? If so do the upgrade on a test server and benchmark if those get issues get better or worse.

Comment: or bugs... I had a machine with a samba server and some nfs mounts and 14.04 would hang at random, and 16.04 doesn't.